# Bind row to a URI using ngTable or similar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

Given a simple ngTable ([plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gmTIo6?p=preview)); how do I link each row to `api/foo/first column`?

(so in that example, clicking first row would send webpage to `/api/foo/Moroni`)

If it's not possible with `ngTable`; I would be happy to accept an answer which uses any other AngularJS table directive (other than `ngGrid`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an ng-click into your row like this

```
ng-click="goto(user.name)"
```

And creating some function in your controller like this

```
var base_uri = "http://sacredgrove.com/";
$scope.goto = function(uri) {
  window.location = base_uri + uri;
}
```

Comment: Switched to using `$location`.